# Как скопировать данные из одной таблицы в другую в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Читаю http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

```
  copy "SC_Tag"."tagdata_2015-01"  ("F_TagName_ID", "F_Date", "F_ConvertedValue")
  to "SC_Tag"."tagdata_2015-01_new" (id_tag, f_time, value)
```

Не получается.

Comment: А вас не смутило, что вверху в описании по ссылке написано "копирование между таблицей и файлом" ?  так что create table, insert into ... select ... from

Comment: как вы определили, что у вас "не получается"? Какие у вас происходят ошибки? Что ожидается получить? Какую конкретно версию PostgreSQL вы используете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для копирования данных между таблицами надо использовать конструкцию

```
INSERT INTO table_dest (fields_list) SELECT fields_list FROM table_src
```

Это позволяет не только копировать данные, но при необходимости и модифицировать их

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы создать новую таблицу на основе данных запроса, воспользуйтесь конструкцией `CREATE TABLE AS`. Синтаксис [тут](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtableas.html)

Для вашего примера получится так:

```
CREATE TABLE "SC_Tag"."tagdata_2015-01_new" 
    ("id_tag", "f_time", "value")
    AS SELECT "F_TagName_ID", "F_Date", "F_ConvertedValue"
        FROM "SC_Tag"."tagdata_2015-01"
```